# How to turn a hex id into a number between 0-100?

Tags: php, math, hash

Simple but puzzling question:

Say I have a string "516e965a8fe4b". I want it to become a number 0-100. Since there's far more than 100 possibilities of having an alphanumeric hash like that, overlaps are fine.

How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Please explain your question more. And it wouldn't hurt if you show us what you already tried, and why that doesn't suit your needs

Comment: You could f.e. add up the ASCII char codes of the single characters, and then take it modulo 100 (or 101, if you want to include the 100 as a possible value). Whether or not that leads to an equal distribution of the values, is for you to figure out ;-)

Comment: Hey you could first convert it to an int with [`hexdec`](http://php.net/hexdec) and then apply a [modulo](http://php.net/modulo) function.

Comment: `(hexdec($value) % 100)` ;)

Comment: function hextohundred($num){return rand() * 100;} //LOL

Comment: Good one @STT LCU :-)

Comment: @STTLCU That off course wouldn't return the same number for the same hex id every time.

Comment: @nl-x  youdontsay.jpg -- what about this then? f($hex){srand(hexdec($num)); return rand() * 100;} //LOL^2

Comment: @STTLCU Now only for the part of rand() not returning a float between 0 and 1 like javascript, but returning an int between $min and $max. But got to say, you're well on your way of returning a serious answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would love to know why you want this. Anyways this is how I would do it.

- Add the ASCII values of each number or letter.
- Then make a MOD 101 of the number. ([Modulus](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php))

  ID= Sum % 101

Comment: If you must know, I wanted a set of existing IDs match up with a list of 100~ things in no particular order. Alcohol was involved. Looks like the question entertained the patrons here :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this. Add the hex value of the numbers and mod it to 100:

```
function findNumber($hash) {

    $sum=0;
    for($i=0;$i<length($hash);$i++) {
        $sum+=hexdec($hash[$i]);
    }
    return $sum%100;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getNumber($string){
    $value = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        $value += hexdec($string[$i]);
    $value = (int)($value/((strlen($string)+.001)*15/100));
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Took me too long to write it. Looks a lot like FloatingRock's answer.

Answer (score 1):

well, i have an alternative approach which is even SAFER than the others, because the result can't be directly determined by the input.

```
function getNumber($hex, $min, $max){
    srand(hexdec($num));
    return rand($min, $max);
}
```

You'll have a number between $min and $max (0 and 100 respectively in your case) which will be always the same every time you run this function with the same inputs (it's deterministic even if it uses random functions!)

Comment: `rand()` doesn't return a float between 0 and 1 like javascript, but returns an int between $min and $max. Try changing into `rand($min, $max);`. See http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: @nl-x  thanks XD i didn't mean to have this as an answer, but i'll go for the lulz :P